# ASP.Net error: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

Tags: iis-6

I had a working asp.net site under development on IIS6 and Server 2003, and then something changed. I reset IIS and now I am getting the error message

```
The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted
```

The IIS logs show the return code as `500 0 2148074244`

I have no idea what happened, but there is nothing in any of the logs indicating why. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the app pool identity. Somehow the service account name lost its domain.

The app pool was running as `app_svc` when it should have been running as `domain\app_svc`.

When the `domain\` was added back to the service account name, everything started working again.