# asp.net Exception: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, authentication

application call handler form other (windows authentication)
application A call handler from application B and application B under windows authentication

when I use the following code exception ( The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted) be displayed
code:

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

```
            webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, password, domain name);                

                string url = (handler url)

                webClient.DownloadFile(url, Context.Server.MapPath(imagePath));
```

Comment: I have two applications (A)anonymous authentication and (B) windows authentication
(A) called Handler from (B)

Comment: Try adding proper domain besides the username. Check whether the credentials are correct & not expired.

Answer (score 0):

In our domain, you need to use need domain to open. e.g Domain\OurUserName

[ASP.Net error: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869757/asp-net-error-the-local-security-authority-cannot-be-contacted)

Comment: I have two applications (A)anonymous authentication and (B) windows authentication
(A) called Handler from (B)

Answer (score 0):

my problem has been solved by updated code to be

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 var credCache = new CredentialCache();
 credCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Negotiate", 
     new NetworkCredential(serviceUserName, servicePassword, serviceDomainName));
 webClient.Credentials = credCache;
 webClient.DownloadFile(url,Path);
```

for help check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791658/system-net-webclient-fails-weirdly)